# Calculate p-value from Estimate and Standard Error in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I am looking for a way to calculate p values from estimates and standard errors in unix.
In `R` for example it can be done by using the following

```
test
BETA       STD
-0.0103312 0.0812054
T=(-0.0103312/0.0812054)^2
p <- pchisq(T,df=1,lower=F)
p
0.8987638
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: This may be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577982/how-to-compute-the-p-value-in-hypothesis-testing-linear-regression

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus a description of how to calculate a "p value". If you're assuming we all know how to read "R" to figure out your requirements and/or we know what "p values" are then YMMV - the intersection between the set of awk experts and the set of R/p-value experts may not be as great as you think.

Comment: What do you mean by "in unix"? Why don't you just use R as it can run on unix?

Comment: By "in unix" i mean that im looking for a way to do it with unix commands. I cant run it in R on unix cause my data is too big and just it just gets stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

using the algorithm 26.2.16 from 
[Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/)

```
awk 'function z(x) {return exp(-x*x/2)/sqrt(2*atan2(0,-1))}
     function p(x) {t=1/(1+0.33267*(x>0?x:-x))
                    return 1-z(x)*t*(0.4361836+t*(-0.1201676+t*0.9372980))}
                   {print 2*(1-p($1/$2))}'
```

will give you two-tailed test p-value.

For your input `-0.0103312 0.0812054`

gives `0.898743`

There are better algorithms with more significant digits which will take longer to implement, but this is good enough if you need a few decimal digits precision.